# A multivariable surjection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, induction

Is the following proof correct ?

**Theorem**. The function $f:\mathbf{Z^+}\times\mathbf{Z^+}\to\mathbf{Z^+}$ defined by the formula 
$$f(i,j) = \frac{(i+j-2)(i+j-1)}{2}+i$$ is *onto*.

**Proof.** We prove that $f$ is surjective by recourse to *Mathematical-Induction* on $n$ in the following proposition.

$$\forall n\in\mathbf{Z^+}\exists i\in\mathbf{Z^+}\exists j\in\mathbf{Z^+}\left(f(i,j)=n\right)$$
For $n = 1$, let $i = j = 1$ thus by using the definition of $f$ we have
$$f(1,1) = \frac{(1+1-2)(1+1-1)}{2}+1 = 1$$
Now assume for an arbitrary positive integer $k$ that there exist positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x,y) = k$ and consider the following cases.

*Case-1($y = 1$):* Let $i = 1$ and $j = x+1$ from inductive hypothesis we know that
$$f(x,y) = \frac{(x-1)\cdot(x)}{2}+x = \frac{(x)\cdot(x+1)}{2}= k$$
consequently 
$$f(i,j) = \frac{(1+(x+1)-2)\cdot(1+(x+1)-1)}{2}+1 = \left(\frac{(x)\cdot(x+1)}{2}\right)+1 = k+1$$

*Case-2($y \neq 1$):* Let $i = x+1$ and $j = y-1$ from inductive hypothesis we know that
$$f(x,y) = \frac{(x+y-2)\cdot (x+y-1)}{2}+x = k$$
consequently
$$f(x,y) = \frac{((x+1)+(y-1)-2)\cdot ((x+1)+(y-1)-1)}{2}+(x+1)$$
$$ = \left(\frac{(x+y-2)\cdot (x+y-1)}{2}+x\right)+1 = k+1$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Your proof is correct. Good job!